# ApplicationBar Icons with text

Tags: windows-phone-7, application-bar

Is there a way to show text along with the icons permanently rather than when a user clicks the "..."?

Or should I instead just use standard buttons instead of the application bar?

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: may i ask how many buttons you want to put in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, if you have maxium two buttons to display on the page, you will probably be fine with standard text buttons, like the screenshot below from the windows phone marketplace. However, you probably don't want any icons on them.

Also try putting a rectangle behind the buttons so it looks like an application bar. :)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know there is no way to achieve what you are telling.. the user should click on the "..." to see the menu...
http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Things-to-consider-when-using-WP7-Application-Bar
http://windows-mobile-dev.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-use-application-bar-in-windows.html

Comment: I know that but the client is being picky and wants it "like iphone"

Comment: Then the client should go for iPhone... I don't think its possible ..You will have to make the client understand about WP7 nativity and its way too different from iPhone or Android..

Comment: i'm doing away with unique components and using popups and regular buttons now. the client already has an iphone version which I am porting to WP7

Comment: You should strongly advise against the IPhone look to your client. This is the Windows Phone. Microsoft invited a complete new look and feel for the phone. The best is to stick with that look and feel because that is what the Windows Phone users are used to. If he want a IPhone looking app he should built an app for the IPhone. The client isn't always right. They hire you because you have the experience. Tell him, as Software Engineer / Expert, that this is not good practice.